# how to export my mysqldata to excelsheet

Tags: php, html, excel

```
    <div style="width:2140px;">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
              <th >Sr.No</th>
        <th >Id</th>
          <th >Fornavn</th>
            <th >Etternavn</th>
           <th >Postnr</th>
        <th >Poststed</th>
            <th >Gate</th>
            <th >Husnummer</th>
            <th >Oppgang</th>
            <th >Etasje</th>
            <th >Leilighet</th>
            <th >Telefon</th>`enter code here`
            <th >Epost</th>
            <th >Campaigns_id</th>
            <th >Ip</th>
            <th >Mc_id</th> 
            <th >Recruiter_id</th>
             <th >utm_source</th>
            </tr>
<?php 
$count=1;
foreach($data as $value)
{
//print_r($value);

?>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $count;?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['id'];?></td>
<?php /*?>   <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['registered'];?></td>
<?php */?><td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['fornavn'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['etternavn'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['postnr']; ?></td>       
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['poststed'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['gate'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['husnummer'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['oppgang'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['etasje'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['leilighet'];; ?></td>       
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['telefon'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['epost'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['campaigns_id'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['ip'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['mc_id'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['recruiter_id'];?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $value['utm_source'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
$count++;
}
 ?>
  <td  colspan="8">  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Export to Excel" name="export_excel" id="export_excel">

     </table>
     </div>

 ****hello i want to export mydata to excelsheet can anyone help me out??
```

thankyou in advance i am showing data on my admin i want to show it on excell onclick of button
ello i want to export mydata to excelsheet can anyone help me out??** 
thankyou in advance i am showing data on my admin i want to show it on excwl onclick of button**

*

Comment: Have a look at PHPExcel: [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate an excel file, just send the right header:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

should define some functions

```
function xlsBOF() { 
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);  
    return; 
} 

function xlsEOF() { 
    echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00); 
    return; 
} 

function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) { 
   echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0); 
   echo pack("d", $Value); 
   return; 
} 

function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value ) { 
    $L = strlen($Value); 
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L); 
    echo $Value; 
    return; 
}
```

You can generate the data in this way:

```
xlsBOF(); 
xlsWriteLabel(7,0,"Cell 1");
xlsWriteLabel(7,1,"Cell 2");
.
.
xlsWriteLabel(7,1000,"Cell n");
xlsEOF();
exit();
```

Comment: its working fine but i want it on click of button now its giving me everytime

Comment: You have to create another page with this code, which is called by clicking on the button.
excel file will be generated and the browser will ask you to save it.

Comment: i have done the same but some how then it not show whole data and it also showing the heading of page alsoo loke other fields

Comment: but my fields are also showing like other page heading and links

Comment: I do not understand what data you do not see.
Put to me the whole script which generates the excel file.
you must use variables that increase the line numbers in the function xlsWriteLabel($count, 3, "data");